# How to set required spacing between two connectors pad on eagle cad soft?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

I have 2 pin screw terminal in my project [like this one.](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8432) But I can't find screw terminals with 7mm spacing between it's 2 pins in eagle library. So, I have decided to use pinhead library to create 2 pin pads for the terminal spaced 7mm apart. I don't know how to space things so that they will fit when I print them out. How do I do it?? Also why is every thing in eagle default in mils and inches? What age are we living in? I know I can change them but I was hoping a company that been in the industry from the beginning would have standardized things. It's a pain in the back when datasheets are in mms and your default is inches. And they don' even let you know that your default is inches.

Comment: Not sure if the rant part about inches is necessary.

Comment: @dim I didn't mean to rant but I was in a bad mood at the time of posting the question. In the library some parts were in inches and some in mm. I had to redo the entire board.

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn how to make your own custom component in eagle. It's easy and you will need it very often. Learning shouldn't take more than a day. Even though pasting links as an answer is not encouraged on this website, I'd suggest you to follow this link: https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/110

It's much better than what I'd write here.

Regarding default inches, a lot of components have pin spacings in inch measurement system. Take TO220, any popular header pins, through hole ICs etc for example. That's why most of your general PCBs also come in 0.1 inch pitch.

Since most of the components are available in 0.1 in pitch, it makes sense for the companies to release their software with a supporting default settings. Obviously many SMD integrated chips are coming which might be following metric systems for pitch spacings, but it's highly unlikely a beginner will work with them. As far as professionals are concerned, they will understand the stuff better and won't complain anyways.

You might ask, why aren't companies switching to metric for all components. The simple reason - backward compatibility. The industry has been sticking to those conventions for too long and switching entire product line means a huge pain for everyone. You won't be able to use new chips in old designs if a part went bad. The companies might have to produce some pieces in inches to provide support for old designs. All this takes too much effort and investment. Not worth it for the companies.

Comment: I didn't mean to rant but I was in a bad mood at the time of posting the question. In the library some parts were in inches and some in mm. I had to redo the entire board. For people like us, it is very hard to visualize inches, since our education system is totally metric. Thanks, now i get it.

Comment: [This might be relevant](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-5dzFpxYcanU/VTorOVU3yOI/AAAAAAAAExs/wOBTP71igC0/s1600/map-of-countries-using-metric-system.png) :)